# How to convert SVG line with marker heads to Png

Tags: javascript, svg

In one of my projects, i am trying to convert a svg to image. Everything is working fine except marker pointers. Can any one please take a look and help me out ? It is working fine on chrome but not on firefox.

Adding the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/L7wt92j4/

```
<marker id="markerArrowLeft" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="13" refX="7" refY="7" orient="-180">
  <path d="M2,12 L2,10 L8,7 L2,4" style="fill: #000000;"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a known [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=841920)